# 502 Server Error Google kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

This morning something has happened with ingress traffic for kubernetes cluster. All websites sites/API:s respond with 502 server error problem.

No updates/changes has been made to cluster or pods. All pods are green and working and all hosts are healty. Everything has been working for more then 2 weeks until this morning.

Do anyone have knowledge with this kind of issue?

Update:

Found 'failed_to_pick_backend' in logs. Strange that could happen after 2-3 weeks..

Answer (score 0):

There could be a thousand of reasons for the failure of pods. Kubernetes has a functionality of self-healing which reconcile till current state is not equal to the desired state.

**Kubernetes**  has accepted it  that **pods** will be crashed, even **nodes** will be failed.

I assume, In your case, Ingress controller is not able to find a healthy pod to deliver traffic. Thus, It's better to check the events of the Pods.

`kubectl get events`

If you want to check out the logs of the previously terminated container from pod POD_NAME.
You can use the following command with -p flag

```
kubectl logs POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME -p
```